# How to decompress tar.gz file in go?

Tags: go, gzip, tar

I have a file called `file.tar.gz` and it has a `folder` inside. Using go I want to decompress it and save the folder in the current directory.

I've found these code on a forum but it doesn't work in my case.

```
package main

import (
    "archive/tar"
    "compress/gzip"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func ExtractTarGz(gzipStream io.Reader) {
    uncompressedStream, err := gzip.NewReader(gzipStream)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ExtractTarGz: NewReader failed")
    }

    tarReader := tar.NewReader(uncompressedStream)

    for true {
        header, err := tarReader.Next()

        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("ExtractTarGz: Next() failed: %s", err.Error())
        }

        switch header.Typeflag {
        case tar.TypeDir:
            if err := os.Mkdir(header.Name, 0755); err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("ExtractTarGz: Mkdir() failed: %s", err.Error())
            }
        case tar.TypeReg:
            outFile, err := os.Create(header.Name)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("ExtractTarGz: Create() failed: %s", err.Error())
            }
            defer outFile.Close()
            if _, err := io.Copy(outFile, tarReader); err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("ExtractTarGz: Copy() failed: %s", err.Error())
            }
        default:
            log.Fatalf(
                "ExtractTarGz: uknown type: %s in %s",
                header.Typeflag,
                header.Name)
        }
    }
}
func main() {
    r, err := os.Open("./file.tar.gz")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf(err.Error())
    }
    ExtractTarGz(r)
}
```

It gives me the error:

```
ExtractTarGz: Create() failed: open go/pkg/linux_amd64_race/unicod/utf16.a: too many open files exit status 1
```

Comment: What does “it doesn’t work in my case” mean?

Comment: I've tried to run the code with my file and it returned an error.

Comment: Does it fail after unzipping some files? The code leaves the unzipped file open until the end of the function (defer outfile.Close()). Instead of that, close the file once io.Copy is done.

Comment: Yes @bserdar it unzips a part of files inside the folder and then crashes. I did as you said but it still crashes on Create().

Comment: Could you show what you did?

Comment: @bserdar of course I just moved close() after io.Copy like this        
            if _, err := io.Copy(outFile, tarReader); err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("ExtractTarGz: Copy() failed: %s", err.Error())
            } defer outFile.Close()

Comment: That's wrong. You're still using defer, which defers the close until the function returns. Use outfile.Close(), not defer outfile.Close().

Answer (score 11):

```
package main

import (
    "archive/tar"
    "compress/gzip"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func ExtractTarGz(gzipStream io.Reader) {
    uncompressedStream, err := gzip.NewReader(gzipStream)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ExtractTarGz: NewReader failed")
    }

    tarReader := tar.NewReader(uncompressedStream)

    for true {
        header, err := tarReader.Next()

        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("ExtractTarGz: Next() failed: %s", err.Error())
        }

        switch header.Typeflag {
        case tar.TypeDir:
            if err := os.Mkdir(header.Name, 0755); err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("ExtractTarGz: Mkdir() failed: %s", err.Error())
            }
        case tar.TypeReg:
            outFile, err := os.Create(header.Name)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("ExtractTarGz: Create() failed: %s", err.Error())
            }
            if _, err := io.Copy(outFile, tarReader); err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("ExtractTarGz: Copy() failed: %s", err.Error())
            }
            outFile.Close()

        default:
            log.Fatalf(
                "ExtractTarGz: uknown type: %s in %s",
                header.Typeflag,
                header.Name)
        }

    }
}
func main() {
    r, err := os.Open("./file.tar.gz")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error")
    }
    ExtractTarGz(r)
}
```

Comment: Code only answers without any text describing what you changed/did and why are not very useful.

Comment: @DaveC in this version he closes without defer.