# How to embed Go Sdk binaries inside of Go Binary

Tags: go, goland, go-build

I actually have a simple goal.

I want to quickly install go in environments without internet access. I want to create a go project in which I add the tar file with the go sdk. When I build my code, I want to extract the tar first and then ınstall the resulting go sdk. But for this, I think I need to add the .tar.gz file into the go binary file.

I am beginner in Go. Does anyone have any idea how I can do it or can I do something like this?

---

Thank you for your advice. I know these things.

You just have to say this.

Is it possible to add a tar.gz file inside the binary file I got with go build command?

When the application is running, it will find the my-tar.tar.gz file in itself, extract it from the tar and process it. So instead of using both a binary and a tar file, I will just use one binary.

Comment: Do you actually need to install the Go toolchain, or can you distribute a prebuilt binary?  You don't actually need the `go` command to run programs written in Go.

Comment: Actually I want to do this operatıons with just one Executable, that why I dont to use Go instead of bash etc. @DavidMaze

Comment: Are you building a Go application to install Go in the target system? You can run the built binary of a Go project without having Go installed on the machine. Can you clarify what's the use case here?

Comment: I know that I don't need Go to run the Go executable. I want to install Go quickly on the servers. For this I want to add the tar files with the Go sdk to my binary file. I wanted to use Go to finish all the operations from just one binary file.

Comment: If you have a tar file with the Go SDK, then you need not statically bind it to the resultant binary instead, you can write the Go code to extract the content of the TAR file using the `tar` package available in the standard library. Ship the tar file and the go binary to the server, read the tar file from the directory where it is present and place it a destination directory

Refer to this to see how to extract a tar file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57639648/how-to-decompress-tar-gz-file-in-go

Comment: "I want to install Go quickly on the servers" That is done through untaring the official release. Why complicate that step? Or asked the other way around: How do you get "your binary" onto the server? You gain nothing.

Comment: what volker said! if you have a lot of server needing the go sdk installed you might also think about using ansible to quickly rollout go (or other things you need) to those server and also being able to update them, etc.

Comment: Just as side info you can always embeed files in the binary with package called "embed" Webservers in golang use this for example for Static content or Templates so that they can just ship the binary. But please consider prev. comments :)

Comment: If you want to embed files, use the [`embed`](https://pkg.go.dev/embed) package. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796043/how-to-embed-files-into-go-binaries (and all the linked duplicates)

Comment: I like how people want to question an OPs goal instead of just answering the question. First class - lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do what you want. No, I would not take this approach for a lot of reasons - but - here is how at a high level:

Use Go's `embed.FS` [capability](https://pkg.go.dev/embed) to get the tarball into your executable.

Note: You will need a different tarball for each architecture, and hence a different build of your executable for every platform. That could be accomplished with [build tags](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/customizing-go-binaries-with-build-tags).

---

Next, you have to extract the tarball after you copy it onto the actual file system. The easiest way would be to just use the `os/exec` package and do an `exec.Command` to run `tar` to extract it.

If `tar` is not on your target machine - then you could use these packages:

```golang
“archive/tar”
“compress/gzip"
```

And follow an approach discussed [here](https://medium.com/@skdomino/taring-untaring-files-in-go-6b07cf56bc07) (a bit dated but generally should still work)

Another interesting thread - do it without having to inflate to the filesystem first:

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/61232

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/nlepage/go-tarfs